# Protractor: Failed: row.findElement is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I have list of elements:

```
 <li ng-repeat="list in lists track by $index">
                    <a href="" ng-click="doSomething($index)">{{list.name}}</a>
                    <button class="destroy" ng-click="remove(list)"></button>
                </li>
```

I am trying to click the last button.

```
it('test', function () {
    var row = element.all(by.repeater('list in lists track by $index')).last();
    row.findElement(by.tagName('button')).click();
});
```

but I get

> Message:
>       Failed: row.findElement is not a function

Comment: What is row.findElement, jasmine or karma function?  Or protractor?

Comment: Protractor [link](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.findElement)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `element()` instead:

```
row.element(by.tagName('button')).click();
```

Comment: i am facing scriptitme out for every element